# Acessing data in a relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a One to Many Relationship between two entities, Fight and FightCard (A fight belongs to a fight card, and a Fightcard can have many fights). The fight entity has a Many to Many relationship with an entity called Fighters. What I want to do is display the details of the Fight entity in the FightCard view (Which is simple, I can do this) but I also what to display the details of the Fighters which have the one to many relationship with the Fight entity.

How can this be done? I hope that made sense.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post code samples so we can see where you are and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included much in the way of code, so here's a basic example that outlines what you're trying to do.

So, let's say you have some entity classes like this:

```
public class FightCard
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fight> Fights { get; set; }
}

public class Fight
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FightCard FightCard { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fighter> Fighters { get; set; }
}

public class Fighter
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fight> Fights { get; set; }
}
```

There's a controller like this with a `Details` action:

```
public class FightCardsController : Controller
{
    private MyContext context = new MyContext();

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        FightCard fightCard = context.FightCards.Find(id);
        if (fightCard == null)
        {
            return this.HttpNotFound();
        }

        return this.View(fightCard);
    }
}
```

Then, you can make a `FightCards\Details.cshtml` view like the following:

```
@model MyProject.Models.FightCard

<h1>Fight Card: @Model.Name</h1>

<ul>
@foreach (var fight in Model.Fights)
{
    <li>
        Fight: @fight.Name

        <ul>
        @foreach (var fighter in fight.Fighters)
        {
            <li>Fighter: @fighter.Name</li>
        }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I removed the code that I had which was fairly similar but the syntax was wrong. Thanks a lot.